# How to initialize an n-sized array after declaration in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

I'm making a text-based RPG kind of thing in C++, and I'm making the *Inventory* class. Here is my code:

```
class Inventory {
    public:
        int size;
        Item items[];

        Inventory(int size): size(size) {

        }
};
```

In the constructor, I need to set `items` to an array of `Item`s with the length of size. I know in Java, I'd just do `this.items = new Item[size]`, but I've been looking for a while now, and even on the cplusplus.com tutorial, it doesn't say how I'd do this. Is there a way? If so, how?

Comment: You cannot, use a `std::vector<Item> items;` instead.

Comment: okay thanks, ill try that. One problem, however, is that I need to limit the size. Can I do this with vectors or would I have to manually limit it (e.g not letting it add more items to the vector once it's too big)

Comment: Depends on how you're actually adding `Items` to the interned vector/array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ doesn't support this regarding raw arrays. The intended thing in c++ is using a `std::vector<Item>` instead:

```
class Inventory {
    public:
        int size;
        std::vector<Item> items;

        Inventory(int size): size(size), items(size) {

        }
};
```

Comment: why should we go for vector? we can solve this by simple 'new' and 'delete' right?

Comment: @GilsonPJ Getting `new`/`delete` right is complicated and peppered with pitfalls you never thought of. The c++ standard container classes were designed to overcome all of these for you. There's no need to reinvent the wheel all the time.

Comment: Dynamic allocation seems a bit over blown for that

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ If I were to use this, would I have to initialize `items`? If so, how

Comment: @ZacGarby _"would I have to initialize items? "_ It's already done in my sample code. Are you asking about initializing individual items?

Comment: no, i just meant like usually you have to use `new`... i think. You do in Java anyway

Comment: @ZacGarby: Java's `new` does a lot more than a C++ `new`. It is very unfortunate that Java's inventors thought it was a good idea to copy the keyword from C++. It has caused endless confusion among Java programmers who learn C++.

Comment: @ZacGarby: P.S.: Why would you use an array in Java and not an `ArrayList`?

Comment: In Java, I'd use an array if I wanted it to not be resizable, shorter to type out or easier to access values (arr[n] instead of arrList.get(n))

Comment: @ZacGarby Do you know the array size at compile time? Rather use a `std::array` then.

Answer (score 2):

Using `std::vector<Item>` is the one and only sane solution here.

In a comment to another answer, you are adding this piece of information:

> One problem, however, is that I need to limit the size. Can I do this
>   with vectors or would I have to manually limit it (e.g not letting it
>   add more items to the vector once it's too big)

A `std::vector` by itself is pretty limitless. Its only real limit is the available memory.

But you should get into the habit of **encapsulating container classes** anyway. Usually, a container class offers way more functionality than you will ever need for one particular use case. For example, your `items` member variable may never require `rbegin()`,  `cend()`, `shrink_to_fit()`, `difference_type`, `get_allocator()` or `pop_back()`, just to name a few examples.

It is therefore good practice to create a custom data type which offers only those operations which you really need, and implement the custom data type **in terms of `std::vector`**. It then becomes trivial to implement additional constraints.

Example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>

// just a super-simple example:
struct Item {
    std::string name;
};

// wraps std::vector<Item>:
class Items {
public:
    Items(int max_size) :
        max_size(max_size),
        items()
    {
    }

    void Add(Item const& item) {
        if (static_cast<int>(items.size()) == max_size) {
            throw std::runtime_error("too many items");
        }
        items.push_back(item);
    }

    Item Get(int index) const {
        return items[index];
    }

private:
    int max_size;
    std::vector<Item> items;
};

int main()
{
    Items items(5);
    try {
        items.Add({ "sword" });
        items.Add({ "shield" });
        items.Add({ "torch" });
        items.Add({ "axe" });
        items.Add({ "boots" });
        std::cout << items.Get(3).name << "\n";
        items.Add({ "gloves" });
    } catch (std::exception const& exc) {
        std::cerr << exc.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Notice that this example uses exceptions to handle the error. This may not be suitable to your use case; you may consider `assert` instead.

Comment: Well, you took the burden at least to explain it to the end. Excellent (I was just too lazy now). Greetings from Bavaria my dear neighbour.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: It must be my old teaching-assistant spirit :) Thanks!